# Англомовний чи англійськомовний?

Tags: вибір-слова

Мовознавці радять використовувати *українськомовний*, а не *україномовний*, бо українська мова, а не мова України, а чи є правила чи рекомендації стосовно інших мов?

Зокрема як буде правильніше сказати: *англійськомовний* чи *англомовний*? Якщо виходити з частоти вживання, то *англомовний* значно попереду (наприклад в Ґуґлі в 10 разів більше результатів) і, чесно кажучи, ніколи навіть не чув і не зустрічав слова *англійськомовний*

Comment: А які це мовознавці радять і де? Можете додати посилання до запитання?

Comment: Особисто мені більше скидається на те, що `україномовний` - це похідний оптимізований варіант від `українськомовний`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### «Україномовний» і «українськомовний»

По-перше, слід сказати, що ідея про бажаність використання «українськомовний» замість «україномовний» підтримується не всіма. Хоча вона має певних прихильників:

- Катерина Городоцька в журналі «Українська мова» від 2012 року № 4 (зацитовано нижче, а також [на форумі R2U](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=3463) і [у блозі Максима](//maksymus.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/500220/));
- [OnlineCorrector](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua/%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9/) (2016);
- Олександр Пономарів в своєму [блозі](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-40718117) (2017) (зацитовано нижче, а також у [відповіді Oksana Gubrenko](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/2556))

— але має і певних критиків:

- «Орфографічний словник української мови» (близько 120 тис. слів, укладач С. Головащук та ін., Київ, «Довіра», 1994, 864 сторінки) містить «україномовний» (на сторінці 782), але не «українськомовний»;
- Світлана Єрмоленко в посібнику «Культурі мови на щодень» (Київ, «Довіра», 2000) [зазначає](http://kultura-movy.wikidot.com/vybir-slova#toc124), що обидва слова побутують у сучасній мовній практиці (і коротше частіше), хоч і мають трішки різну конотацію (також цитується [в блозі Максима](//maksymus.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/500220/));
- «Великий тлумачний словник сучасної української мови» (2005) містить «[україномовний](//www.lingvolive.com/en-us/translate/uk-uk/%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)», але не «українськомовний»;
- [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) (2008) містять обидва слова без нотаток щодо переваг одного над іншим;
- «Російсько-український словник» у 4-х томах (Київ, «Знання», 2014) містить «україномовний», але не «українськомовний»;
- Максим (Maksymus) (засновник спільноти ua_etymology і учасник декількох інших спільнот про мову, що, на мою особисту думку, зазвичай характеризуються продуманістю своїх тверджень) в своєму блозі [критикує](//maksymus.wordpress.com/2017/07/24/500220/) (2017) пуризм Катерини Городоцької і спроби витіснити слово «україномовний».

#### «Англомовний» і «англійськомовний»

Але річ у тім, що навіть прихильники вживання «українськомовний» замість «україномовний» не агітують за використання «англіськомовний» замість «англомовний». Тобто маємо, що:

- Катерина Городоцька, торкаючись цієї теми (2012, див. вище) і згадуючи слова «англомовний», «іспаномовний», нічого не каже про небажаність таких слів (лише про правильність «українськомовний» замість «україномовний»):

  > Дехто вважає, що людей, які розмовляють українською мовою, потрібно називати *україномовними*, подібно до *англомовних*, *іспаномовних* та ін., незважаючи на те що ці складні прикметники тісніше пов'язані з назвою країни, ніж із назвою її мови. Інші заперечують проти вживання *україномовний*, тому що немає *росіємовний*, *польщемовний*. Замість нього пропонують уживати *українськомовний*, бо він точніше відбиває зв’язок з українською мовою. За таким самим зразком утворені складні прикметники *російськомовний*, *німецькомовний*, *чеськомовний* та ін.
  > Отже, людей, які розмовляють українською мовою в Україні та за її межами, правилльно називати *українськомовними*.
- Олександр Пономарів (2017, див. вище) каже, що вживаніші варіанти: «англомовний», «франкомовний» (але «іспанськомовний», «німецькомовний»):

  > Щодо слов'янських мов — потрібно вживати *українськомовний*, *білоруськомовний*, *польськомовний*, *російськомовний*. Не кажемо ж ми *поломовний*, *чехомовний*.
  >
  > Щодо инших мов — уживаніші варіянти *франкомовний*, *англомовний*.
  >
  > Але *німецькомовний* та *іспанськомовний*.

Додатково дивимося словники:

- [«Словники України on-line»](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/dictua/) (2008) містять «англомовний»/«англомовність», але не «англійськомовний»;
- «Словник української мови» в 20 томах (2010–…) містить «[англомовний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=184995&page=49)»/«[англомовність](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=188845&page=49)», але не «англійськомовний».

P. S.: Катерина Городоцька згадує «іспаномовний», Олександр Пономарів радить «іспанськомовний» — «Словник української мови» в 20 томах (2010–…) все-таки за «[іспаномовний](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=186917&page=1251)».

#### Висновки

Для тих, кому ліньки читати:

- Щодо «україномовного»/«українськомовного» — думки розходяться.
- Щодо «англомовного»/«англійськомовного» — навіть той, хто агітує за «українськомовний», наполягає на «англомовному».

Answer (score 5):

У [цій статті](http://probapera.org/publication/13/25257/bezkoshtovno-chy-bezplatno-bezoplatno.html) автор пропонує тезу добору питомого ключового слова:

> "Це так як правильніше буде **українськомовний**, а не україномовний, **англійськомовний**, а не англомовний, тому що у перших випадках мається на увазі **мова**, а в інших – країна."

Це виключно теорія, а не практика/використання мови.

Люди говорять так, як склалося, а не так, як вважають в кабінетах окремі "науковці." (до речі, у тексті за посиланням не все добре з грамотністю:) )

Answer (score 5):

[Професор Пономарів диференціює](http://www.bbc.com/ukrainian/blog-olexandr-ponomariv-40718117) між слов'янськими та іншими мовами.

> Читач Дмитро хоче знати, якими з варіянтів і коли варто послуговуватися: *україномовний* і *українськомовний*,
>   *іспаномовний* та *іспанськомовний*. Також йому цікаво, в яких випадках доречно вживати *французькомовний* і *франкомовний*,
>   *англійськомовний* і *англомовний*.
>
> Щодо **слов'янських** мов - потрібно вживати ***українськомовний***,
>   ***білоруськомовний***, ***польськомовний***, ***російськомовний***. Не кажемо ж ми *поломовний*, *чехомовний*.
>
> Щодо **инших** мов - уживаніші варіянти ***франкомовний***,
>   ***англомовний***.
>
> **Але** ***німецькомовний*** та ***іспанськомовний***.

Як на мене, цьому підходу також бракує аргументації.

Втім, за відсутності альтернативних обгрунтувань, наводжу як відповідь.